# Wifi network listing freezes on Nexus 4 after Lollipop update

Tags: wi-fi, settings, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, system-freeze

I have a Nexus 4, and finally decided yesterday to update to Android 5.0, after being fearful of bug reports.  And wouldn't you know it, I've found a nasty bug.

Nearly every time I try to display the list of Wifi networks in the Settings, the system freezes for about a minute, then I get prompted saying

> Settings isn't responding.
>   Do you want to close it?
>   REPORT WAIT OK

If I wait long enough (by hitting 'wait' or 'report'), then I eventually get the list of wifi networks, and everything appears to work normally* from that point.

If it's relevant, my phone also has the problem described in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/62025/13613), and the update to Lollipop didn't fix it.  So I'm thinking a factory reset may be in order....

<sub>*I say normally, I had to wait a similar amount of time to authenticate to the network at Starbucks through the authentication web site, but once I was authenticated, everything appeared to work normally. I have no idea if this is actually a related problem, so I only mention it in passing.</sub>

Comment: I won't be any consolation, but I have the exact same symptoms you observe on my Nexus 4 and have been search forever for a solution and no suggestion I tried works.

Comment: @kynan: Did you try a factory reset and it didn't help?

Comment: I did not, but considering it since it has become pretty much unbearable...

Comment: I had something similar happen to a friend. Just switched wifi off and back on and it worked. Can't suppose you haven't tried it though.

Comment: I did a factory reset from the official Google images and have the same bug on my Nexus 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently and solved it by removing old saved networks in the WiFi settings. I found that there were a huge number of networks with names that were strings of letters and numbers.

1. To remove saved networks open 'Settings' and choose 'Wi-Fi' (and
   wait for it to load).
2. From the 3-dot menu choose 'Saved networks'.
3. You should see a list of networks in a similar format to those shown below:
   [image: WiFi Listing]
4. Remove any you don't recognise (tap the network name and tap 'Forget'):
   [image: WiFi Delete]

Once all of the unrecognised names have been removed the list of WiFi networks should load without freezing the system.

NOTE: I have found that this can occur again after a while, in which case repeat the steps above.

Comment: I didn't find any "unrecognized names"... but there were a ton of wireless networks stored after 2+ years of extensive travel and connecting to random networks all over the place.  I have removed those I don't frequently use, and will see how things perform now.  Thanks for the tip.